# sql query to like some texts

Tags: php, mysql

My site is like imdb.com - it stores movie details and actor's names. In my actor field, I'm storing actors name like "name1,name2,name3,name4".

My site has the option to search movies by actor name.  My code for this is below:

```
SELECT * FROM imdb WHERE actors LIKE '%%actorname%%'
```

The problem is that if a visitor searches for 'Lal', then movies with actor's named 'Mohanlal' and 'Lal' will both appear.  I only want to list the 'Lal' movies. How can I write the query to do that?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM imdb WHERE actors LIKE 'actorname%'`

Comment: You should normalize your schema. Add a table with one row for each actor in each movie, and use a join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `imdb` WHERE `actors` RLIKE '[[:<:]]Lal[[:>:]]'
```

Even better, and easier:

```
SELECT * FROM `imdb` WHERE find_in_set('Lal',actors)
```

Comment: woooww..its superb..but there is a small problem if there is a name like "Nanda Lal" its also showing

Comment: Then try the second query ;-)

Comment: superb..thanx alot... some where i used space between name and comma so i can use one more condition using OR right??

Comment: SELECT * FROM `imdb` WHERE find_in_set( 'Lal', actors ) OR find_in_set( 'Lal ', actors ) OR find_in_set( ' Lal', actors ) OR find_in_set( ' Lal ', actors )

Comment: If performance is still high enough, you can do that. Otherwise it would be better if you correct the erroneous values​​.

Answer (score 0):

Make the query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM imdb WHERE actor LIKE 'actorname'
```

and put a text next to your inputfield to let them use wildcards for search. Then, if they want to search for 'Lal', the will only find 'Lal', if they want to search for everything that ends on 'lal' (%lal), they will find Mohanlal and Lal.

Comment: But there is problem is i am storing actors names in field like actor1,actor2,actor3..if search like this lal is actor aded in second then it will not retrieve

Comment: So, you mean you have 1 table that has the movie in it, and all the names of the actor? All in one row? So the actor you are looking for can be either in field actor1, actor2, actor3? If so, you can use SELECT * FROM imdb WHERE actor1 LIKE 'actorname' OR  actor2 LIKE 'actorname' OR actor3 LIKE 'actorname' OR actor4 LIKE 'actorname'...

Comment: but there is no sure how many actors will be in a movie..if there is 50 actors?? what to do??

Comment: You do have a fixed number of possible actors in your table, so you set the number of actors to check on equal to the number of actor-fields in your table.

Comment: there is no fixed number..thats the problem.No one can predict now days movie actors list right?? if the movie like avengers how many actors are there :D

Comment: No, indeed, that is why you shouldn't store your movie details and your actor details in the same table. You should create a relational database layout for this, so that you can put all the movie details in one table, the actor details in another table, and add a third table to create a many-to-many relationship between movies and actors. This way, to get all the movies a certain actor plays in, it would be: SELECT * FROM movies, actors, actors2movies WHERE actors.actor_id = actors2movies.actor_id AND move.movie_id = actors2movies.movie_id AND actors.name LIKE 'actorname'

Comment: but its making more complication bro :(

Comment: Yes, but you can't put complex data into an simple database-layout, and keep all the code simple too...

Comment: pls check this
SELECT * FROM `imdb` WHERE `actors` RLIKE '[[:<:]]Lal[[:>:]]'  
only problem of this code is name like 'Nanda Lal' also showing ..all other are perfect

Answer (score 0):

You should have created separated table for actors, anyway we will try to find solution of what we are left to.

```
  SELECT * FROM imdb WHERE actors LIKE 'Lal,%' OR actors LIKE '%,Lal%' OR actors = 'Lal'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM imdb WHERE actor LIKE '%,lal' or actor LIKE 'lal'
```

Comment: but there is other actors called Lalu alex and Newlalu then what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

```
SELECT whatever
FROM whereever AS t
WHERE t.actors = SOUNDEX('test')
```